# Tkinter.filedialog não funciona com o ToastNotifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou criando um assistente virtual que se comunica com o usuário através de mensagens de notificação. Eu pesquisei muito na internet sobre e achei o `win10toast`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aí o programa está funcionando perfeitamente, porém hoje, fui implementar uma função para o usuário definir diretórios para o assistente realizar buscas de programas e outros no computador.

**Código para selecionar um diretório:**

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory,askopenfilename

def getDirectory():

    Tk().withdraw()
    path = askdirectory()
    return path
```

O problema é que ele não funciona. Ele não abre uma janela para selecionar um diretório. Eu testei retirar do código a parte que usa o `win10toast` e funcionou a função `getDirectory()`.

**Código para mostrar a mensagem do assistente:**

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

class MessageBox(object):

    def __init__(self,icon=None):
        self.__icon = icon
        self.__toastNotifier = ToastNotifier()

    def send(self,title,message,duration=5,threaded=True):

        # Se eu retirar este método a função getDirectory funciona.
        self.__toastNotifier.show_toast(
            title,
            message,
            icon_path=self.__icon,
            duration=duration,
            threaded=threaded
        )
```

**Exemplo de execução:**

```
messageBox = MessageBox() #Inicializar um objeto de ToastNotifier não gera problemas para o getDirectory.

# Se eu retirar essa linha, o getDirectory funciona.
messageBox.send("Jarvis","Aperte Windows + S para falar.",threaded=False) #Envia mensagem

command = assistant.listen() #Retorna uma string

if command.lower() == "adicione caminho":
    path = getDirectory()

    if path and not path in paths:
        paths.append(path)
```

O que pode estar gerando este problema e como posso resolvê-lo ?
Eu sei que existem problemas parecidos como [este](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/517) e que existe solução, porém no meu caso essa solução não funciona.

Comment: o cóidog acima não tem a chamada aao "win10toast", e portanto, "funciona perfeitamente". Não vejo como alguém vai poder te ajudar a não ser que você coloque um exemplo mínimo com código que _apresente_ o problema (em outras palavras: incluindo a inicialização e chamada ao win10toast, do jeito que você está fazendo)

Comment: Ok vou colocar na pergunta, mas não acho muito necessário porque o win10toast possui somente uma classe com 3 métodos sendo um para aparecer a notificação, outro para verificar se a notificação está ainda ativa e outro para executar algo ao destruir a notificação.

Comment: como eu disse - sem isso, o código funciona, então não há o que responder

Comment: Pesquisando, eu encontrei problemas parecidos que tinham solução como por exemplo este: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/517. Porém no meu caso essa solução não funcionou, então eu pensei se alguém que entenda a fundo sobre como funciona o filedialog consegue me responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu ainda não consegui entender a causa do problema mas fazendo vários testes, consegui encontrar a solução para meu programa.

O problema por algum motivo era causado quando eu passava para o parâmetro `thread` o argumento `False`. Esse argumento faz com que a mensagem, no caso o método `show_toast`, seja executado dentro de uma Thread. Passando para esse parâmetro o valor `True` a função `getDirectory` funciona perfeitamente.

Mas agora fica uma dúvida no ar. Eu sei que o Tkinter deve ser executado sempre no main Thread, ou seja, na execução principal. Mas por que ele estava dando problema se o que estava sendo executado fora do main Thread era o método `show_toast` ?